# How to set user defined command for ssh connect

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I currently use Terminal to connect the cluster by:

```
>ssh -p port user_name@address
>user_name@addresspassword's:
>password
```

I want to creat a user defined command, simply like `connect` and a configure file containing those essential elements

```
# These contents can be edited
port: xxxx
user_name: xxxx
address: xxxx
password: xxxx
```

After those setting, I want to connect the cluster by simply typing 'connect' in the terminal.

Comment: If you specifically don't want key authentication and instead want the less-secure password approach, take a look at https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/noninteractive-shell-script-ssh-password-provider/

Answer (score 3):

Install `sshpass` first.

```
apt-get/yum install sshpass -y
```

Add this to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
connect()
(
    . ~/.ssh/variables_for_ssh.sh
    SSHPASS=$password sshpass -e ssh -p "$port" "$username@$address"
)
```

Create a file called `variables_for_ssh.sh` in `~/.ssh/` (or some other directory that's only readable by you), with this content:

```
password='yourpassword'
port=portnumber
username='your username'
address='your address'
```

And then change the permissions, so that only you and root can read and write the file.

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/variables_for_ssh.sh
```

When you change the content of `variables_for_ssh.sh`, just source your `~/.bashrc`, before running `connect`.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing some things: You need to `source` the file with the variables to have them appear in the current shell, just `sh` would spawn an independent shell to lead them and then do nothing. Don't use `sshpass -p`, it makes the password visible in the output of `ps` (I think the man page even warns about that). Also, if you have `'$password'` in single quotes, it's not even expanded. I also think something like `~/.ssh` might be a better place than `/tmp` for such a file.

Comment: @ilkkachu, thanks for the edit! Just one thing, what if he does not have root access?

Comment: Does that matter other than for installing `sshpass`? They should have access to their own home directory regardless, and they need it to modify `.bashrc`, too

Comment: It would matter if the permissions for `variables_for_ssh.sh` are 700 and the user's `.bashrc` is sourcing the variables.

Comment: `0700` means all permissions for the file owning user (+ implicitly to root since they can override everything). If they create the file in their own name, they can access it just fine. Of course, if `root` creates a file with those permissions, then the user can't access it.

Comment: I see, was a bit confused there.

Comment: (`0600` would probably be better, there's no need for execute permission)

Answer (score 0):

Edit 
~/.ssh/config:

```
Host Address
User user_name
Hostname address
Port xxx
```

Now you can connect with

```
 $ ssh Address
```

If you want to shorten it further add an alias to

```
~/.bashrc:

 alias connect="ssh Address"
```

You should set up an ssh public key and place it in the remote server to allow passwordless secure login.

It is not good idea to store the password in plaintext or shorten a command like the sshpass one with an alias (which again would store the password in plain text), see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/87956/392575)